# Adding SUM per node ID to Views in Drupal 6

Tags: views, 6

I have a list of IDs, and these IDs have several amounts associated with them.

I need to sum the amounts per ID, and spit that out as the amount.

Here's my query alter:

```
function my_module_name_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_module_name') {
    $query->add_groupby('nid');
    $query->fields['credit_amount']['aggregate'] = TRUE;
    $query->fields['credit_amount']['field'] = 'SUM(amount)';
  }
}
```

This is the ultimate output, but it doesn't work:

```
       [credit_amount] => Array
            (
                [field] => SUM(amount)
                [table] => my_module_table
                [alias] => credit_amount
                [aggregate] => 1
            )
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? How do you group by an ID field (in this case, nid from an organic group node) but aggregate an amount field per that node? The query would look essentially like this:

```
select n.title, sum(lf.amount) from node as n
join credit as lf on (n.nid = lf.og_node)
group by lf.og_node
```

This is in Drupal 6

Comment: I can not give you a hint how to do it in D6, but your query does not seem correct to me. If you do not group by n.title or remove n.title from the selected fields it will not work as you expect.